# Why is the docker buildx build command hanging?

Tags: docker, gradle, arm, amd-processor, buildx

> I am runing the command docker buildx build --push  --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64  -t steinko/gradle-ci-cd .
> o/gradle-ci-cd .
> The comand is hanging

```
[+] Building 2108.8s (20/23)                                                                                                                                                           
 => CACHED [linux/amd64 gradleimage 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/gradle@sha256:9b0871b0061cae621a5f9ca67359da36810e5aeae3a917f4c78ae3cbed6313a5                                    0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/gradle@sha256:9b0871b0061cae621a5f9ca67359da36810e5aeae3a917f4c78ae3cbed6313a5                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                 0.4s
 => => transferring context: 17.15MB                                                                                                                                              0.4s
 => CACHED [linux/amd64 stage-1 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/openjdk@sha256:fa5414c6c4f8f836308947ae46daf65f2bce39ac01e89edfbe730cd0703dca06                                       0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/openjdk@sha256:fa5414c6c4f8f836308947ae46daf65f2bce39ac01e89edfbe730cd0703dca06                                                                  0.0s
 => [linux/arm64 gradleimage 2/5] COPY ./app /home/gradle/source/app                                                                                                              0.1s
 => [linux/amd64 gradleimage 2/5] COPY ./app /home/gradle/source/app                                                                                                              0.1s
 => [linux/arm64 gradleimage 3/5] COPY settings.gradle /home/gradle/source/settings.gradle                                                                                        0.0s
 => [linux/amd64 gradleimage 3/5] COPY settings.gradle /home/gradle/source/settings.gradle                                                                                        0.0s
 => [linux/amd64 gradleimage 4/5] WORKDIR /home/gradle/source                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [linux/arm64 gradleimage 4/5] WORKDIR /home/gradle/source                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [linux/amd64 gradleimage 5/5] RUN gradle build                                                                                                                             2106.6s
 => => # > Task :app:jar SKIPPED                                                                                                                                                      
 => => # > Task :app:assemble                                                                                                                                                         
 => => # > Task :app:compileTestJava                                                                                                                                                  
 => => # > Task :app:processTestResources NO-SOURCE                                                                                                                                   
 => => # > Task :app:testClasses                                                                                                                                                      
 => => # > Task :app:test                                                                                                                                                             
 => [linux/arm64 gradleimage 5/5] RUN gradle build                                                                                                                               34.4s
 => [linux/arm64 stage-1 2/3] COPY --from=gradleimage /h
```

> My Docker file looks like this

```
FROM gradle as gradleimage
COPY ./app /home/gradle/source/app
COPY settings.gradle /home/gradle/source/settings.gradle
WORKDIR /home/gradle/source
RUN gradle build

FROM openjdk
COPY --from=gradleimage /home/gradle/source/app/build/libs/app.jar /app/
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

> My Gradle file looks like this

```
plugins {    
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.5'
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.4.5'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.4.5') 
    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:spring-mock-mvc:4.3.0'
    testImplementation  'io.rest-assured:rest-assured-common:4.3.1'
    
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

> How do I fix the hanging?